# Not presenting Authentication view controller game kit ios 7

Tags: objective-c, authentication, gamekit, ios7

I am on ios 7 and with this code:

```
-(IBAction)authenticateLocalPlayerWithViewController
{

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *receivedViewController, NSError *error){

        if (receivedViewController != nil)
        {

            [self presentViewController:receivedViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated) {

            signinButton.hidden = YES;
            leaderboardButton.alpha = 1.0;
            leaderboardButton.enabled = YES;
            achievementsButton.alpha = 1.0;
            achievementsButton.enabled = YES;


            NSString *identifier;
            [self reportAchievement1Identifier:identifier percentComplete:((interactiveHighscore/10000)*100.0)];
            [self reportAchievement2Identifier:identifier percentComplete:((interactiveHighscore/100000)*100.0)];
            [self reportAchievement3Identifier:identifier percentComplete:((interactiveHighscore/1000000)*100.0)];
            [self reportAchievement4Identifier:identifier percentComplete:((interactiveHighscore/100000000)*100.0)];
            [self reportAchievement5Identifier:identifier percentComplete:((allCoins/100000)*100.0)];

            [self submitMyInteractiveScore];
            [self submitMyNormalScore];

            BOOL isRunMoreThanOnceGC = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isRunMoreThanOnceGC"];
            if (!isRunMoreThanOnceGC) {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Game Center Sign In Gift"
                                      message:@"Thanks for signing in with game center here is 50 Coins."
                                      delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks!."
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

                allCoins = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"allCoins"];
                allCoins += 50;

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isRunMoreThanOnceGC"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


            }
        } else {

            signinButton.hidden = NO;

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Game Center Not Available"
                                  message:@"Uh Oh! Seems there was an error trying to sign in for Game Center. Try logging in through the Game Center app."
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, Thanks."
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }

        NSLog(@"Error: %d", [error code]);
    };
}
```

am trying to authenticate the user. First on the root controller's viewDidLoad I call it with this:

```
//get game center
LeaderboardsViewController *LVC = [[LeaderboardsViewController alloc] init];
[LVC authenticateLocalPlayerWithViewController];
```

Then I get this:

Error: 0
Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

So I try to press the button in the gamecenterviewcontroller class (thats where the authenticate method is) and I get nothing. Nothing in the log and nothing appears....

Running ios 7 GM Build.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I put a link because I didn't want to spam the readers. But I will from now on thanks for the pointer Abizem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to re-create the method in the same class. Cannot present a view controller from a external class/